# Why can I buy a ticket on gotogate/other resellers but not direct?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, bookings, bulgaria

Today my friend flew from Zurich to Sofia with Bulgaria air. 
The flight was not available on the Bulgaria Air website but only through gotogate and the other resellers.

We bought the flight, and she flew, and the flight was mostly empty.
Why would the airline not have sold these seats? Is this common?

Comment: airline website have errors... like all others.

Comment: Note this airline is not profitable, operates both the Boeing 737 and the Airbus 320 despite having very few planes -- their reservation system being glitchy is the least of their problems.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a fare that is only offered through a certain agent, not by the airline itself. Airlines sometimes have special arrangements with agents/resellers. Those get discounts for talking a gzaranteed number of tickets, or for dealing with customers requests or other sich things. Not all fares have to be available directly from the airline.